# Java - Wrap each call in a block with a function

Tags: java, data-structures, wrapper

Is there a way in java to turn a code block like this:

```
{
wrapper(a.put(...));
wrapper(b.get(...));
...
...
...
wrapper(c.remove(...));
wrapper(c.get(...));
wrapper(a.get(...));
wrapper(b.put(...));
}
```

where a,b,c are some generic data structures, with varying methods,
into a similar block without the constant mentions of "wrapper"?
to get something along the lines of:

```
{
x.put(...);
y.get(...);
...
...
...
z.remove(...);
...
...
}
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean?  What's stopping you?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you elaborate your question please? People who try to help could have not enough context to do so. You should ask a question which doesn't require any effort to be understand. **The more you give , the more you get** : Put a little effort in your questions, and people will give you good answers.

Comment: A clear example with some real types would definitely help increasing the clarity and quality of your question.

Comment: That example looks way to abstract to me and I don't think that is really what you want to do.  Is `wrapper` really just a method that does something if a value returned from all of those other methods? It is quite rare for `put` and `remove` to return anything actually.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
// As args used only once, you don't strictly need the variable.
List<MyType> args = List.of(
    a.put(...),
    b.get(...),
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    c.remove(...),
    c.get(...)
);
for (MyType arg : args) {
    wrapper(arg);
}
// Or, er:
//   args.forEach(WrapperClass::wrapper); // static wrapper()
//   args.forEach(this::wrapper);         // instance wrapper()
```

Is that what you mean?

**Edit:** For the simple case:

```
List.of(
    a.put(...),
    b.get(...),
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    c.remove(...),
    c.get(...)
).forEach(this::wrapper);
```

(As ever, I've not so much as tried to compile this.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use lambdas, especially if you want the same evaluation order, but:

- a, b, c must not be assigned more than once.
- Very artificial.
- It is still ugly.

The following would execute in the same order:

```
void wrapper(R result) { ... }

Stream<Supplier<R>> tasks = Stream.of(
    () -> a.put(...),
    () -> b.get(...),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    () -> c.remove(...));
tasks.map(s -> s.get())
    .forEach(s -> wrapper(s.get()))
```

A simpler solution without lambdas (as already given) would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DynamicProxy, or Spring AOP.